# pg_stat_replication empty after failover

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, repmgr

I have set up a 3 node cluster, where the streaming replication is without any problems set (done through docker-compose). 
When i stop the primary, a new primary is then chosen, and the previous standby switches to the new primary. 
But the problem is that the streaming replication is not set. Whatever i do on the primary is not replicated to the standby, and if i try to query select * from pg_stat_replication, it's empty.

I'm not sure if i'm missing something from the docs that is related to this, or is it necessary to fix the replication manually.

If someone can give a tip, i would be really thankful.

Link to the Dockerfile, Docker-compose and scripts, along with some crucial logs and pg_stat_replication database: [Link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repmgr/3_YBFWTxPJs/LmYHAbqfCQAJ)

I think that i miss something really obvious.

Cheers.

Comment: You should give more information: is repmgr configured to handle this ? if yes, please give details. Please give also PostgreSQL logs from primary and standby starting before primary stop.

Comment: @pifor Updated the original post with the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as described [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/5589#issuecomment-962750900)

After adding the following [in the preStop](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql-repmgr/issues/66#issuecomment-945656214), I am not having this issue/

```
while [ $(pgrep -f /opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin/postgres) ]
```

Also, if possible set the `synchronous_commit = remote_apply` so that all the nodes are in sync.